# Should a table view/collection view clip under the home indicator on iPhone X?

Tags: ios

I can't figure out from reading the Human Interface Guidelines which of these two are correct for table views / collection views:

**1. Going below home indicator**
[image: below home indicator]

**2. Going up only to the safe area**
[image: to safe area]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, Option 2 looks better; the idea of the safe area should be to say inside it. And in this video, https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/201/, Apple explicitly says to avoid the home indicator:

[image]

Nevertheless, in the very same video, Apple clearly shows a table view scrolling behind the home indicator:

[image]

That's presumably because the table view scrolls, so no information is actually lost as long as the content can be scrolled all the way up past the indicator.

I would also suggest watching this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/801/ (especially starting at 9.37 where the home indicator is specifically discussed). The statement there is that *nonscrollable* content should stay inset from the home indicator; this implies, by contrast, that for something like a table view, it's okay to scroll behind the home indicator, as they show here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! As pointed out in the video you referenced (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/801/) @11m45s: "vertically scrollable Views, such as Tables or Collection Views, should extend all the way to the bottom of the display, rather than being constrained to the Safe Area".

Answer (score 0):

After updating a couple apps recently here's my starting point.

(And watching all the WWDC videos circa iPhone X launch...)

**If the table is only content**, let it flow under the home indicator. General reason: if the table stops at the safe area, it looks abrupt, even if the background under the home indicator matches the table.

The user intuits that the indicator is on top, and the auto-coloring feature of the indicator will take care of itself. If the user wants to scroll the table content, "they know what to do".

**If the table has controls**, then it is ideal to obey the safe area. You can use matching background or table-is-a-rectangle (safe area is the void), depending on larger design approach.

(Even if you want to be clever and put the controls in the gaps between the corners and the home indicator, who knows if the width of the home indicator will change in future iOS versions (or if the corners will change in future screen types)?

This might be the answer for every reader's case, but hopefully this nudge's you in a d